# Возможно ли из аудиоплеера сделать интернет радио плеер?

Tags: java, android, json, mediaplayer, exoplayer

Есть библиотека на **github** (аудиоплеер) который воспроизводит музыку находящуюся на устройстве. Возможно ли переделать этот плеер таким образом, чтобы он строил такой же список из объектов - (есть уже готовый **JSON**, парсинг данных из него в список, и проигрывание этих объектов через плеер **ExoPlayer** в своём приложении).

Библиотека **github**: [X-Music-Player-Pro](https://github.com/srivnaimish/X-Music-Player-Pro)

Сам вопрос в следующем: Как, что и где менять нужно в этой библиотеке, чтоб приложение не брало музыку с устройства, а загружало "список станций" из этого самого **JSON** файла.. В общем, заменить это самое место в коде, где музыка с устройства забирается.

**P.S:** в моём приложении, **JSON** файл лежит в папке **/assets**, парсится оттуда, создается списком как нужно. То есть нужно просто изменить код в библиотеке этого плеера, чтобы брал нужные данные вместо музыки с устройства. Заранее благодарю, если покажите с чего нужно начать, и что менять.

Comment: возможно, распарсить ваш JSON, подсунуть URL & AUDIO_STREAM в MediPlayer. в либе Service придется корректировать. Только как на ваш вопрос ответить? Переписать за вас ? Там все что угодно мб.

Comment: Я не могу понять в каком классе парсится музыка с устройства в приложение.

Comment: В либе Service найдите, MediaService , чтот тип того, я мельком поглядел, вроде всё там делается.

Comment: Да возможно. Но что касается этого плеера - забей. Там очень много завязано на работе с файловой системой, чтение/обработка треков. Может подсунуть ссылку на стрим, вместо файла, у тебя и получится, но все остальное у тебя сломается. Без серьезного вмешательства в код у тебя ничего не выйдет.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека сильно завязана на ContentProvider и структуре системного сервиса поставки информации о медиа ресурсах MediaStore.Audio.Media (C одной стороны очень хорошо).

Чтобы сильно не править исходники, можно сделать следующее:

1) Cоздать свой ContentProvider, который будет дублировать функционал сервиса MediaStore.Audio.Media (клон, c такими же таблицами и названиями полей).

Касательно таблиц и названия полей, можно найти тут:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html

2) После в библиотеке X-Music-Player-Pro все вызовы типа:

`new CursorLoader(getContext(), musicUri , null, selection, null, order);`

заменить параметр musicUri, указав путь к вашему созданному ContentProvider (клон сервиса MediaStore.Audio.Media***).

3) В итоге вы сможете спокойно модифицировать список воспроизводимых данных.